# Cannot run through loop to getAllPassengers

Tags: java, count

Hey i want to loop through planes to get all passengers and add them to a count to display all passengers for all planes.  But im getting an error: Cannot iterate over an array or an instance.

**Here is the method:**

```
public int getAllPassengers()
    {
        int passengers = 0;
        for(Plane plane : plane.getPassengerNumber())
        {
            passengers += plane.getPassengerNumber();
        }
        return passengers;
    }
```

**Plane**

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Plane implements Comparable
{   
    private String flightNumber;
    public String airlineName;
    private double fuelRemaining;
    private int overdue;
    private int passengerNumber;
    private AIRPLANETYPE planeType;
    private boolean isLanded = false;

    public enum AIRPLANETYPE
    {
        AIRBUS("1"), CORPORATE("2"), PRIVATE("3");

        private String planeName;

        private AIRPLANETYPE(String planeName)
        {
            this.planeName = planeName;
        }

        public String getPlaneName()
        {
            return this.planeName;
        }
    }

    public Plane(String flightNumber, String airlineName,
           double fuelRemaining, int overdue, int passengerNumber, 
           AIRPLANETYPE planeType, boolean isLanded) 
    {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
        this.airlineName = airlineName;
        this.fuelRemaining = fuelRemaining;
        this.passengerNumber = passengerNumber;
        this.overdue = overdue;
        this.planeType = planeType;
        this.isLanded = isLanded;
    }


    public Plane() 
    {

    }


    public String getAirlineName() {
        return airlineName;
    }

    public void setAirlineName(String airlineName) {
        this.airlineName = airlineName;
    }


    public void setOverdue(int overdue) {
        this.overdue = overdue;
    }

    public int getOverdue(){
        return overdue;
    }

    public String getFlightNumber() {
        return flightNumber;
    }

    public void setFlightNumber(String flightNumber) {
        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
    }

    public double getFuelRemaining() {
        return fuelRemaining;
    }

    public void setFuelRemaining(double fuelRemaining) {
        this.fuelRemaining = fuelRemaining;
    }

    public int getPassengerNumber() {
        return passengerNumber;
    }

    public void setPassengerNumber(int passengerNumber) {
        this.passengerNumber = passengerNumber;
    }

    public AIRPLANETYPE getPlaneType() {
        return planeType;
    }

    public void setPlaneType(AIRPLANETYPE planeType) {
        this.planeType = planeType;
    }


    public boolean isLanded() {
        return isLanded;
    }


    public void setLanded(boolean isLanded) {
        this.isLanded = isLanded;
    }


    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        if((arg0 != null) && (arg0 instanceof Plane))
        {
            Plane p = (Plane) arg0;
            return (int)Math.ceil(this.overdue - p.getOverdue());
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Plane: flightNumber=" + flightNumber + "."
                + " airlineName=" + airlineName + "."
                + " fuelRemaining=" + fuelRemaining + " litres."
                + " overdue=" + overdue + " minutes."
                + " passengerNumber="+ passengerNumber + "."
                + " airplaneType=" + planeType +
                "hasLanded=" + isLanded+ ".\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over an `int`, you need to iterate over an [`java.util.Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Your posted code does not contain the information needed to answer this question.

You are showing us the class `Plane`, but in order to have more than one plane, you probably have a `List<Plane>` or a `Plane[]` somewhere else in the code. Here's one example that would work:

```
public class Main {
  List<Plane> allPlanes; // Load in the omitted code somewhere else

  public int getAllPassengers()
  {
    int passengers = 0;
    for(Plane plane : allPlanes) // note the change
    {
        passengers += plane.getPassengerNumber();
    }
    return passengers;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`passengerNumber` is an `int`. You need to iterate over an `Iterable` such as an `ArrayList`:

```
for (Plane plane: myPlaneList) {
  passengers += plane.getPassengerNumber();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is an iterable.

Comment: Something which implements `Iterable` and thus has an `iterator()` method. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Comment: It's an [ìnterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) implemented by all the commonly used [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to iterate through Plane objects, but your collection is just an int. You'll need a collection of Plane objects

```
int passengers = 0;
for(Plane plane : myPlanes)
{
    passengers += plane.getPassengerNumber();
}
```